# Regex.Replace replaces empty match

Tags: c#, regexp-replace

I'm using the following regex to only replace lines that are not empty (lines with whitespaces do not count as empty).

`^(.+)$` with the multiline option.

According to regex101 this should work: https://regex101.com/r/S5Fcqw/1

But it seems that C#s implementation of regex is a bit different. Can I make this work with replace or do I need to look at match?

This is the call: `Regex.Replace(text, @"^(.+)$", "    $1", RegexOptions.Multiline);`

Language is C# 7.2 and net472 as target framework.

So I have now found the offending combination:

```
        public static string IndentBy(this string text, int count, string indentationMarker = " ")
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                return text;
            }

            var spaces = string.Join(string.Empty, Enumerable.Repeat(indentationMarker, count));
            var replacement = $"{spaces}$1";
            var indented = Regex.Replace(text, @"^(.+)$", replacement, RegexOptions.Multiline);
            return indented;
        }

        [InlineData("a", "    a")]
        [InlineData("a\nb", "    a\n    b")]
        [InlineData("a\r\nb", "    a\r\n    b")]
        [InlineData("a\n\nb", "    a\n\n    b")]
        [InlineData("a\r\n\r\nb", "    a\r\n\r\n    b")] // this line fails
        public void IndentBy_Input_GivesExpectedOutput(string input, string expected)
        {
            // act
            var indentet = IndentBy(input, 4);

            // assert
            indentet.ShouldBe(expected);
        }
```

Comment: Your regexes don't match. Can you show a [mre]? Also, `\r\n` != `\n`

Comment: I agree. Maybe setup a short sample with https://dotnetfiddle.net/
Also it would help if you can just write down the input and expected output here.

Comment: I must have miss something because I don't see an issue in the result. https://dotnetfiddle.net/WHXVU7. Can you provide and input that cause the issue, the result you got, and the result you want?

Comment: @CodeCaster fixed. I was playing around when I copied that line. Sorry about that.

Comment: @DragandDrop You haven't missed anything. It's working for you. Let me check what else can be the problem on my side.

Comment: @RedX, I will also ask for what newline char you have at the end of the line and what is the version of C# you are using. This may just be because \n is the new standard in .net because of multi platform.

Comment: Im talink about ; https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/standard/base-types/string-comparison-net-5-plus , and https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/standard/globalization-localization/globalization-icu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the fix was to not rely on `$` to match the newline but to do it manually.

I use now: `@"([^\r\n]+\r?\n?)"` with `RegexOptions.SingleLine` (not sure if necessary) and it works fine for my use-cases.